# Why tail -f is not working for a proc file?

Tags: tail, proc

I have a `proc` file which is updated by a driver. In user space I am reading using `tail`. It is working fine, But when i give `-f` option for tail, It is not working. This means it is reading file contents which are already there but it is not reading new contents that added later.Can somebody explain why?

Comment: http://superuser.com/a/155214/28322 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [discussion the Linux Kernel Mailing List](https://lkml.org/lkml/2001/10/10/152) in 2001, `proc` was not built with support for the underlying code calls used by `tail -f`.  I have not found any evidence that such support was added in the last 12 years.